# Как создать несколько объектов в одном контроллере?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть стандартный контроллер `OrdersController` и есть 3 модели: `Modelone`, `Modeltwo`, `Modelthree`. Необходимо сделать так, что бы у каждой модели была своя страница с формой создания объекта данной модели.

Если в контроллер просто прописать например метод:

```
def modelone
  @modelone = Modelone.new(params_modelone)
end
```

соответствующими стронг параметрами - то рельсы выдают ошибку во вьюхе **views/orders/modelone.html.erb**. Буду признателен за "пошаговый" ответ.

```
= form_for @modelone do |f|
  = f.text_area :description

  = f.submit
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: undefined method `modelones_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f03f45b20a8>:0x007f03febfdd40>
Did you mean?  modelone_path - хотя в routes стоит get 'modelone', to: 'orders#modelone' и ссылка link_to 'Modelone', modelone_path

Comment: Обратите внимание у вас представление требует modelones_path, во множественном числе, а роуты и экшен задают единственное число modelone_path.

Comment: Ну да, это я заметил., но о чем это говорит понятия не имею.

Comment: Пожалуйста дополните свой вопрос кодом из представления, что вы делаете в нем, что происходит обращение к такому роуту?

Comment: добавил, форма в haml

Comment: Заменил @modelone в форме на Modelone.new - та же фигня. Это в принципе возможно, создавать в одном контроллере объекты разных моделей? Или необходимо для всех моделей свой отдельный контроллер с new действием делать? У меня сейчас около 60 моделей, делать для каждой отдельный контроллер, что бы в каждую прописать одну и туже форму - выглядит как то чрезмерно.

Answer (score 1):

В контроллере напишите просто вызов отрисовщика по модели:

```
@object = Modelone.new # or two or three

render "orders/#{@object.class.to_s.underscore}_form"
```

и файлы соответственно:

1. **app/views/orders/modelone_form.html.slim**
2. **app/views/orders/modeltwo_form.html.slim**
3. **app/views/orders/modelthree_form.html.slim**

Comment: Не работает (хотя уверен что это мой косяк). В контроллере orders_controller в действии def new - добавляю @modelone = Modelone.new . Затем в views/orders создаю файл с формой modelone_form.html.haml. Затем в orders/home.html.haml добавляю = render "orders/#{@modelone.class.to_s.underscore}_form" . Выдает ошибку Missing partial orders/_nil_class_form

Answer (score 1):

`form_for` ожидает ресурсный роут. Если в него передать Modelone.new, он попытается создать форму с `action` равным `modelones_path` этот метод неопределен, так как в роутах у вас нет `resources :modelones`.

можно передать `form_for` url как опцию, например:

```
 form_for @modelone, url: 'путь к экшену-обработчику формы'
```